# SharePoint 2010 - Picture library - number of listed pictures - paging

Tags: picture-library, picture

I'm got a image picker, that's a picture library that that lists picture 1-30 in each paging. How can I increase the number of image listed on each paging?

I want each paging to have 100 images listed.

PS: New information. Show some examples with code. "picture" - on the root node is my "picture library"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to picture library, from the ribbon click on library -> modify view -> item limit, you can see item limit is set to 30, change it to 100

Comment: Nice! But what If I want to change it by code?

Comment: You can do that easily get the SPView (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview_members.aspx) object of the corresponding view set RowLimit attribute to 100 and then Update the view